# Possible to share resources (logging, database, file etc.) across Python subproccesses?

Tags: python, subprocess

I've written a large program in Python that calls numerous custom modules' `main` methods one after another. The parent script creates some common resources, like logging instances, database cursors, and file references which I then pass around to the individual modules. The problem is that I now need to call some of these modules by means of `subprocess.check_output`, and I don't know how I can share the aforementioned resources across these modules. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The question exactly as you ask it has no general answer.  There might be custom ways; e.g. on Linux a lot of things are actually file descriptors, and there are ways to pass them to subprocesses, but it's not nicely Pythonic: you have to give them as numbers on the command line of the subprocess, and then the subprocess rebuilds a file object around the file descriptor (see `file.fileno()` and `os.fdopen()` for regular files; I'm not sure there are ways to do it in Python for other things than regular files...).

In your problem, if everything is in Python, why do you need to make subprocesses instead of doing it all in a single process?

If you really need to, then one general way is to use `os.fork()` instead of the `subprocess` module: you'd fork the process (which creates two copies of it); in the parent copy you wait for the child copy to terminate; and in the child copy you proceed to run the particular submodule.  The advantage is that at the end the child process terminates, which cleans up what it did --- while at the same time starting with its own copy of almost everything that the parent had (file descriptors, database cursors, etc.)